# How to make an object from a class table print as a table in stargazer?

Tags: r, markdown, stargazer

I'm using a markdown document to write text from R. At some point, I want to add a table that I calculated using the `table()` function. But it's not working.

```
library(stargazer)
x=structure(c(2075L, 49L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("0", "1")), .Names = ""), class = "table")

stargazer(x)

Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Stargazer accepts model objects. To see the list of supported objects use help("stargazer models").  It can also provide summary statistics for a data frame as given in the other answer by @sbstn.

Comment: See the answer below, I think it can handle data frames.

Comment: reread my comment :-P ?

Comment: Hahaha I forgot to turn off my skim reading. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
stargazer(as.data.frame(x),
          type = 'text',
          summary = FALSE,
          rownames = FALSE)
```